# create a data-frame given number of replicates

Tags: r, dataframe

I am creating a function which ideally should generate a single `data.frame` from multiple replicates, my approach is very 'manual' and I am wondering what is the better/idiomatic way to do this.

```
get.summary <- function(dta,n){
  t1 <- get.random_sample(dta,n)
  t2 <- get.random_sample(dta,n)
  t3 <- get.random_sample(dta,n)
  t4 <- get.random_sample(dta,n)

 c.dta <- rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4)
 return(c.dta)
}
```

Ideally I want to provide the number of replicates to the function such that I can have more than 4 or less without hard coding them.

For example:

```
get.summary(dta, n, replicates)
```

I have tried a `for` loop but it does not provide the desired output. Any ideas on how to generate the final `c.dta` without hardcoding the number of replicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
r1 <- replicate(nreps,get.random_sample(dta,n),simplify=FALSE)
do.call(rbind,r1)
```

?